# Bash get filename from SVN log XML using regex

Tags: regex, xml, bash, svn, grep

I've got svn log XML file and I want to retrieve changed files.

`<Paths>` can consist one or many child elements named `<Path>`.

In this case I want to retrieve `/trunk/server/sub/sub1/scripts/fix/filename.sql`.

**Content of issues.xml (fragment):**

```
<paths>
    <path
        action="A"
        prop-mods="false"
        text-mods="true"
        kind="file">/trunk/server/sub/sub1/scripts/fix/filename.sql</path>
</paths>
```

To do that, I am using following bash script:

```
#!bin/bash
filenames=($(grep -oP '<path[^>]*>(.+?)<\/path>' "issues.xml"))
echo $filenames
```

The output of this script is empty. I have no clue why. I've tried to output all array elements in a loop but that didn't work, too.

Any advice?

Comment: Do not use text processors for parsing `XML`, use a proper `XML` parser like `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try with this:

```
grep -oP '([^>]*)(?=</path>)' file
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Can you explain more why your regex works and mine doesn't?

Comment: Your regex is matching against two different lines of input. `grep` will work with one line at the time. So, I have used `lookahead` method to match only `.*</path>`.

Answer (score 3):

Using standard text processors for parsing `XML` is generally *NOT* recommended.

Suggest use a proper XML parser like `xmllint` or `xmlstarlet` which deals with your file even when the original file goes thorough a formatting change (e.g. a new white-space getting added) the regex used for the extraction needs to undergo a change.

Using `xmllint` with an `xpath` expression is literally too-easy. For your given input file, just do,

```
xmllint --xpath 'string(//path)' file
/trunk/server/sub/sub1/scripts/fix/filename.sql
```

Steps to [download and install `xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/downloads.html) are pretty straight-forward.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not install additional libraries in my situation.
Thank you for your solution anyway!

Comment: @Alex: Fair enough, but am going to keep this answer, if its fine. Because the below regex solution works only for your input provided, if your input file formatting changes, the solution needs to be changed again, but that is not the case with `xmllint`